# How to save object of class with dict inside to set

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I want to create a class, objects of it should store a dict and put it into an object of another class which store objects of first class as set.

I'm parsing xml model of DB, domains for now, in format like this

```
domain name="BinData" type="BLOB" align="L"/
```

and want to have set of all domains and each attribute of domain as pair key:value.
I know that you can't do it just putting dict to set. But maybe I can handle this in classes? 
What I have tried:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
class schema:

    def __init__(self,xdb_file):
        self.xdb_file = parse(xdb_file)
        self.domains = self.get_domains()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.domains == other.domains):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_domains(self):
        domains_set = set()
        domains = self.xdb_file.getElementsByTagName("domain")
        for domain_description in domains:
            domains_set.add(domain(domain_description.attributes.items()))
        return domains_set

class domain:
    def __init__(self,items):
        self.description = dict()
        for item in items:
            self.description[item[0]]=item[1]
        self.description = (self.description)
    def description(self):
        return self.description

    def __eq__(self, other):
        is_Equal = True
        if (set.difference(self.description,other.description)):
            return True
        return False
```

In the end, it shows mistake about unhashable type domain.

Comment: ***mistake*** is what we need to help you.

Comment: A `dict` is not hashable, so you cannot create a set of `dict`s.

Comment: File "D:/Projects/GroupDevelop/tests/xdb_to_ram_classes.py", line 52, in get_domains
    (domain(domain_description.attributes.items()),))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'domain'

Comment: You need to define your own `__hash__` method for `domain` that doesn't make use of `self.description`. The hash has to take into account only the immutable parts of an instance of `domain`. In this case, there don't appear to be any immutable parts.